# apache nifi data provenance time issue

Tags: apache-nifi

Istalled apache nifi on dev and prod envs
On dev everything is ok
prod apache nifi installed on aws and on prod I have strange thing with apache nifi data provenance.
If I check data search 29.12.2020 - it shows me 11.09.2020
Before I have this issue - helped set Timezone in java.
But know the same thing.
Time in nifi and server is correct
[image: search2]
[image: search]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]

```
{"provenance":{"request":{"maxResults":1000,"summarize":true,"incrementalResults":false,"startDate":"12/29/2020 00:00:00 EST","endDate":"12/30/2020 23:59:59 EST","searchTerms":{}}}}
```

Comment: screenshots and request/response api would be helpful.

Comment: screenshot it's not a problem.
About api - it's hard, i'am newbie in nifi

Comment: open devtools->network in your browser (usually f12 key) then click search, then you should see api request to server. find request (it should be small). response we already see on a screenshot. and what is your nifi version?

Comment: Added screenshots

Comment: You missed the most important thing - request payload

Comment: Added under pictures

Comment: any recommendations?

Comment: Please help, I can't find a solution...

Comment: truthfully - i can't reproduce this issue on local nifi. seems you have non-standard provenance parameters. please add to your question nifi version, java version, and all nifi.provenance parameters from nifi.properties file.